# Problem with base+gain of signals

Tags: mimic-iii

There seems to be a problem with the gain/base when correcting the base/gain of several subjects. For example  the gain/base of subject a44012am (mimic2db) should 512 /255 respectively (according to the .info file), but the ABP signal results in values between -50 to 10 mmHg, although the ATM web presentation seems to have reasonably physiological values.

Used the following command:

```
wfdb2mat -r mimic2db/a44012/a44012a -f 137110 -t 137170 -l s1000000 >a44012am.info
```

Is it possible the the gain/base values in the .info file are wrong?